# How can I speed up this object detection algorithm?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-learn, random-forest

Im trying to calculate the centroid and angle of an object. Right now, it takes me about ~7,8 seconds to generate the output for a given image.

To calculate the output for a given image, first of all i generate some features applying filters like Gaussian, Median and Variance. Then, feed it into an sklearn RandomForestClassifier previously trained model to generate a segmented image (ths is the part that takes most of the time). Let's assume that after this point, the post-process/calculations are already fully optimized. What could i do to speed up the process?

---

**Example 1**
[image: 1]

---

**Example 2**
[image: 2]

---

Is it possible to split the original image into minor images in order to parallelize the process?
Are there better/faster alternatives to correctly segment the original image?

Any idea/recommendation is appreciated.